# Angular app page refresh gets stuck when chrome dev tools window is open

Tags: angular

I have an angular app which uses angular 7. When I do a change to the angular code, angular reloads the chrome webpage automatically.

When I have a chrome dev tools window open when this auto refresh happens, the refresh gets stuck. I can see that chrome is taking a high CPU consumption, but it is not able to render the page.

Even when I close the dev tools window when chrome got stuck like this, it doesn't recover. Only if I close the dev tools window before the refresh starts, chrome is able to show the page.

I only encountered this issue about a couple of weeks back. Earlier it used to work fine without an issue.

What could be the reason for this. I am unable to migrate to angular 8 yet due to some reasons, so upgrading angular is not a viable solution for me right now.

Comment: in google developer console, enable "Preseve Log" option to have logs even after page reloads.

Comment: maybe take a look at the code as well. If chrome is taking high CPU consumption there might be something else going on, for example subscriptions being open and incrementing every time reload happens?

Comment: @AJT82 But why would it only happen when dev tools is open

Comment: When dev tools is open, the console is logging. Logging data in the console uses a lot of resources. If you have long loop of log, it may affect your CPU this way...

Comment: @Random I commented out all the console logs, but issue is still there